# Linux: Agent Side Checkout fails - Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset

Tags: teamcity, perforce

Using Team City 2017.1

I am unable to use Agent Side checkout with my Ubuntu 14.04 build agent due to the following error:

```
[2017-06-22 13:41:12,779]   INFO -   jetbrains.buildServer.VCS.P4 - Running p4 login for user myUserId in [P4Port: redacted-server-address:1666; P4User: myUserId; perforce client mapping with 1 rules, VCSRoot: "ETG" {internal id=170}]
[2017-06-22 14:07:38,029]   INFO -   jetbrains.buildServer.VCS.P4 - Creating P4 workspace TC_p4_LinuxBuildAgent1_964e0a7b4154cd8c_85d77afe3e61a99a
[2017-06-22 14:07:38,225]   INFO -   jetbrains.buildServer.VCS.P4 - Creating/updating Perforce client specification:
Client: TC_p4_LinuxBuildAgent1_964e0a7b4154cd8c_85d77afe3e61a99a
Owner:  myUserId
Description:
        Created by TeamCity for user myUserId.
Root:   /home/someuser/BuildAgent/work/964e0a7b4154cd8c
Options:        noallwrite clobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime rmdir
Host:           ubuntu
SubmitOptions:  revertunchanged
LineEnd:        local

View:

        //ETS/GE_DEV/Build/...  //TC_p4_LinuxBuildAgent1_964e0a7b4154cd8c_85d77afe3e61a99a/...

[2017-06-22 14:07:38,436]   INFO -   jetbrains.buildServer.VCS.P4 - Running p4 login for user myUserId in [P4Port: redacted-server-address:1666; P4User: myUserId; perforce client mapping with 1 rules, VCSRoot: "ETG" {internal id=170}]
[2017-06-22 14:07:39,016]   WARN - l.patch.AbstractSourcesUpdater - Error while checkout on agent: Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset. - while running 'p4 -c TC_p4_LinuxBuildAgent1_964e0a7b4154cd8c_85d77afe3e61a99a -u myUserId -p
 redacted-server-address:1666 -H ubuntu client -i'
jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsException: Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset. - while running 'p4 -c TC_p4_LinuxBuildAgent1_964e0a7b4154cd8c_85d77afe3e61a99a -u myUserId -p redacted-server-address:1666 -H ubuntu client -i'
        at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.perforce.PerforceConnection.runCommand(PerforceConnection.java:271)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.perforce.PerforceConnection.runCommand(PerforceConnection.java:257)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.perforce.PerforceWorkspacesImpl.createOrUpdateWorkspace(PerforceWorkspacesImpl.java:80)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.perforce.PerforceAgentSourceUpdater.createOrUpdateLocalWorkspace(PerforceAgentSourceUpdater.java:99)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.perforce.PerforceAgentSourceUpdater.updateSources(PerforceAgentSourceUpdater.java:68)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.perforce.PerforceAgentSourceUpdater.updatePerforceSources(PerforceAgentSourceUpdater.java:55)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.perforce.PerforceSourceUpdatePolicy.updateSources(PerforceSourceUpdatePolicy.java:66)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.vcs.AgentVcsManagerExImpl$CheckoutSupportImpl.updateSources(AgentVcsManagerExImpl.java:108)
        at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.ProjectSourcesOnAgent$1.run(ProjectSourcesOnAgent.java:186)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am fairly certain our Perforce server uses ticket based auth. At the build machine, I can run **p4 login** (which prompts for password). This is successful and allows me to run **p4 client** which returns a User specification that includes an "AuthMethod: perforce" (the user specification **does not** include a "Password:" line).

I have tried a couple of different workarounds including:

- Creating a .p4enviro file which includes the P4PASSWD
- Setting an environment variable for P4PASSWD (in /etc/environment)

However, these have no effect...

The logs seems strange to me because the login appears to succeed (at least, no errors are logged). But, the checkout fails with the P4PASSWD error.

Also, the VCS root is using a Client mapping (but I have tried it with Client as well - same error is present).

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Are you running the "p4 login" as the same user on the system that the build agent runs as?  The ticket file (as well as the enviro file) is stored in the current user's home directory by default.

Comment: Please check /Users/buildAgentUser/.p4tickets file for the account build agent runs under - is it writable and accessible? Build agent should be able to write to the file. Also, do you have P4TICKETS variable set to some non-default value?

Comment: @SamStafford - I found out that the build agent was being started via rc.local and thus running as root instead of the buildAgentUser that p4 login was successfully working with. So, I was able to correct that issue and now agent-side checkout is working!

Comment: @KIR - please see my above comment to Sam Stafford. Essentially, you guys guessed the issue and I now have agent side checkout working! However, this has caused a different problem; now the agent fails when trying to connect to the Team City server to download artifact dependencies (which works when running as root). Would there be any reason that a less privileged user wouldn't be able to download artifacts? Also, the Team City server is running on a separate Windows box if that helps.

Comment: @Rob I think build agent has created some temporary directories when it was running under root, and now, when it is running under ordinary user, build agent cannot write files into these dirs. Run "sudo chmod -R buildAgentUser /path/to/buildAgent"  and it should help.

Comment: @KIR - thank you very much, that solved the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved thanks to those who added comments above.

This issue was self-inflicted and caused by an entry in rc.local that was issuing the start command to agent.sh (thus causing the build agent to run as root).

If I would have just [RTFM](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Setting+up+and+Running+Additional+Build+Agents#SettingupandRunningAdditionalBuildAgents-AutomaticAgentStartunderLinux), I wouldn't have encountered this issue :)